# How do I attach a JS click event to an AJAX loaded button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, devexpress

I need to attach a JavaScript click listener to an add new record confirmation on a DevExpress gridview. 
I can't use a regular click event listener as it's loaded via AJAX integrated into the control. I also have no access to the button's code so am unable to extend it.The only thing I do have is the button name.

Ideally I want to listen for the appearance of the button on the DOM and then attach the listener, is there any way to do this?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/on/ - event delegation.

Comment: use .on() to attach your event handler to all elements including those that are not created yet http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Cute username, but shouldn't that be `Inverted ɐɯɐll` or even `ɐɯɐll pǝʇɹǝʌuI` :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do not need to wait for the appearance of the button in the DOM.

Just use a *delegated event handler* attached to a *non-changing ancestor* of the dynamic elements.

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '.someclass', function(){
   ///
});
```

If you only have the element name for the button use an attribute selector:

e.g.

```
$(document).on('click', '[name="somename"]', function(){
   ///
});
```

Delegated events work by listening for events bubbling up to a non-changing ancestor (`document` is the default if nothing closer is available). It *then* applies the selector at event time (not at event registration time). It *then* calls the function *for any matching element that caused the event*.

The end result is that it will work with elements that may exist later, when the event occurs.

*Note: if nothing is closer to the dynamic content, use `document`, but do not use `'body'` as styling can make it have a zero height and delegated mouse events will not work!*

Comment: This saved me, in a scenario where my button on-click handler was being wiped out by Ajax in an ASP.NET application. Delegating the click handler to the document level fixed that because the document wasn't affected by Ajax, only a particular div was. Brilliant!